# Plural / Singular verb in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Recently an editor just changed the plural verbs in my essay to singular ones, but I don't understand why he did so. Please see below:

(Original sentence)
After rising to power through multiple revolutions, the Chinese Communist Party holds a subversive notion and ideology that not only **aspire** to break the old world, but also **aim** to build a new one.

(revised sentence)
After rising to power through multiple revolutions, the Chinese Communist Party holds a subversive notion and ideology that not only **aspires** to break the old world, but also **aims** to build a new one.

In my understanding, there are two nouns in "a subversive notion and ideology", and that should be followed by a plural verb?

Comment: I suspect that they are construing those to be the same thing.

Comment: Thanks tchrist, So, in this sense, they treated "a subversive notion and ideology" as an uncountable mass noun, and thus used singular verbs?

Comment: It's still countable, I'd say, but it is one compound thing. I'm not sure what *notion* adds to your sentence to be honest. I think *ideology* might be better by itself.

Comment: Got it, thanks tchrist and Minty!

Comment: Just adding the article ***an*** before ideology changes the singular phrase to plural items (just like "*the fish and the chips are tasty*", compared to "*the fish and chips is tasty*").

Comment: Seriously, how can "a subversive notion and ideology" be a single thing? "A bad attitude and behavior account for his being punished."

Comment: Calling these "singular" or "plural verbs" is a little weird. You would say "He runs" but "I run." Both involve one noun. Which is a "singular verb" and which is "plural?"

Comment: @scohe001 They are both singular. The *s* in the conjugation is irrelevant to determining the number. When you have a singular verb, you are talking about its conjugation for a singular subject. *He runs* and *I run* both use singular subject verbal conjugations. *They run* uses a plural subject verbal conjugation. It's contextual.

Comment: @scohe001 A verb has a third-person singular ending (aka morpheme, s/es. Or: A verb is in the singular or in the plural.

Comment: Would you write "...the party holds ideology and a subversive notion that aspire..."?

Comment: what does holding a notion mean?  doesn't a notion have to be a notion of something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key is in the use of the indefinite article.

To paraphrase:

> The CPP holds **a** <sup>subversive notion and ideology</sup> that **aspires** . . .

I have put the subject in superscript in order to set it off from the rest of the text. Especially because of the ***a***, the syntax treats the phrase as a compound single subject.

It is the same idea as:

> **This** <sup>fish and chips</sup> **is** delicious.

Although there are actually two separate things joined together, they are thought of, and treated as, a singular item.

---

In order for the syntax to show that there are *multiple* things being used as individual subjects, you would need to remove the indefinite article and pluralize the subjects:

> The CPP holds subversive **notions** and **ideologies** that **aspire** . . .

Alternatively, it's possible to use a phrasing similar to what follows—but it would be somewhat awkward:

> The CPP holds **a** subversive notion ***as well as*** **a** subversive ideology that ***both*** aspire . . .

Comment: Many thanks, Jason, your explanation is very clear!

Comment: Would *"a subversive notion and **an** ideology that aspire ..."* also be correct?

Comment: @JiK Yes, that works too. I exaggerated the distinction in my answer because it more clearly separates the two, but it's not essential.

Comment: @JiK But note that a second article isn't *always* sufficient to make something plural. For instance: ***A*** *wing and **a** prayer **isn't** enough.* That's an idiomatic phrase with two indefinite articles that's still treated as something singular.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. tchrist and Minty are right I think. But are both the notion and the ideology subversive? It isn't quite clear. And can a notion itself aspire to do something? Perhaps an ideology can, but I'm not sure. I would leave *notion* out, and say something like

> "The CCP's subversive ideologies suggest that it aspires not only to break the
>   old world but also to build a new one."

Comment: Got it, thanks Old Brixtonian! Your revised version looks better!